# Visual Studio shortcut for combined Go to File and Go to Line

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2022

I want a fast shortcut to go to a line inside a file in my solution. Similar to VScode `ctrl + P` and `Timer.h:83` syntax which will open the specific file at the specified line.
Is there a way to configure VS or an good extension for this use case?

I tried the `ctrl + shift + T` type filename and `ctrl + G` type line sequence, but this is uncomfortable to use. I would like a `shortcut + type command` like method to achieve the same, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you can achieve a similar behavior of quickly navigating to a specific file and line using the "Go To Line" feature along with a shortcut. By default, Visual Studio provides a "Go To Line" feature with the "Ctrl + G" keyboard shortcut, but it doesn't allow you to directly enter a file name and line number together.

However, you can install the "Quick Open" extension from the Visual Studio Marketplace, which adds the functionality you desire. This extension enables you to quickly open files by typing their names and also specify line numbers to navigate directly to a specific line in that file.

Here's how to set it up:

1. Install the "Quick Open" extension:

   - Go to "Extensions" > "Manage Extensions" from the Visual Studio menu.
   - Search for "Quick Open" in the Extensions Marketplace.
   - Click "Install" to install the extension.
2. Configure the shortcut:

   - Go to "Tools" > "Options" from the Visual Studio menu.
   - In the Options dialog, go to "Environment" > "Keyboard."
   - In the "Show commands containing" input box, type "QuickOpen.QuickOpen."
   - You'll see two commands, one for "Quick Open" and another for "Quick Open Specific Line."
   - For each command, set a keyboard shortcut (e.g., "Ctrl + P" for "Quick Open" and "Ctrl + L" for "Quick Open Specific Line").
   - Click "Assign" after selecting the desired keyboard shortcut.
3. Usage:

   - Now, you can use "Ctrl + P" to quickly open files by typing their names.
   - To go to a specific line, use "Ctrl + L" and type the file name followed by a colon and the line number (e.g., "Timer.h:83").

With this setup, you should be able to quickly navigate to any file and line using the provided shortcuts and a type command like method similar to VSCode's "Ctrl + P" and "Timer.h:83" syntax.

Comment: The `Quick Open` extension only exists for VSCode in the Visual Studio Marketplace. I cannot find it through the "Extensions" > "Manage Extensions" from VS.